# Magento 2 : How to upload image from frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, image-upload

I want to add a feedback form in frontend, with an image upload field, How to save form data and images in database?

Answer (score 10):

First, you should be  add **input type  file at  form** and also add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` and

```
    <!-- -->
    <div class="field image">
        <label class="label" for="image"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Image') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input name="image" id="image" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('image') ?>"   type="file" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

At controller, you need  upload image via

> Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory

***Add below class in __construct functions and  execute function of controller:***

```
 <?php
 namespace [Namespace];

use  Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
class [MyClass]
{

 protected $uploaderFactory;
 protected $adapterFactory;
 protected $filesystem;

    public function  __construct(
            .....
            \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
            .....
    )
    {
        .........
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    }
     public function execute()
    {
        try{
            $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
            $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
            $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
            /* start of validated image */
            $uploaderFactory->addValidateCallback('custom_image_upload',
                $imageAdapter,'validateUploadFile');
            $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('custom_image');
            $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);
            if (!$result) {
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                );
            }
            /* you need yo save image 
                 $result['file'] at datbaseQQ 
            */
            $imagepath = $result['file'];
            //
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }
}
```

## Note

`$destinationPath` give the path till `magentoDir/pub/media/custom_image`
 and $result content below

[image]

Comment: How to call this model from controller?

Comment: How to uploads multiple images ?? i have tried with foreach but not succeed

Comment: @amit I want to do same validation in Magento 2.3, so can you please help me how to deal with exception? because when I'm trying to submit form using ajax call, I'm getting Exception error in controller, and not getting response in ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I just have a suggestion for you. We can follow the same logic of product file option. We can see how Magento works with the file.

Here is a sample template:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/type/file.phtml`

And take a look at

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/AbstractType.php
public function processFileQueue() { ..... }
```

I think it's a good example for uploading image on frontend.